# Laravel: No such file or directory for table in AWS RDS laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I currently deployed my laravel app to the AWS elastic beanstalk. I created RDS mysql database. I imported my sql dump from my local project and deployed it to the AWS EC2 server. But I'm getting this error.

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `settings` where `code` = company-name limit 1).

Is there any way how to check if there are data in my DB ? Just to note I'm still learning moving around AWS. Thanks.

EDIT :

I'm also getting correct Environment & details like RDS_PORT RDS_HOST... , on error page where I can see the error displaying

Comment: Please check security groups are configured correctly or not? Please test your connection with mysql cli.

Comment: I can log in mysql cli with command mysql -u root -p -P and so on .... , let me check the security groups

Comment: my instance and RDS are using the same security groups

Comment: In elasticbeanstalk, you need to define environment variables from the console. did you do that? Please follow the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console

Comment: I will have a look thanks

Comment: @ShaileshMatariya I tried this but nothing happens at all :(

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial to connect to a MYSQL RDS Database on AWS.
So you can check if all your tables have been created successfully.

[AWS Connect to Database Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html)

Make sure that you open the port of the RDS database in the security group. Otherwise your local machine can't connect to the Database.